# Get 2 values from ONE selectbox (optgroup and option selected) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me with this, I have a selectbox that looks like this:

```
<select name="scatid">
<optgroup label="June">
  <option>2005</option>
  <option>2006</option>
  <option>2007</option>
  <option>2008</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="July">
  <option>2005</option>
  <option>2006</option>
</optgroup>
```

and I also have an empty inputbox...

What I'm trying to achieve is, if for example I select from the selectbox year 2008 (June optgroup)... the inputbox value get's automaticaly the text "June 2008" (optgroup name + option selected)... etc etc..

Can somebody give me an example how can I achieve this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the label by reading `label` property of the `optgroup` element:

```
$('select[name="scatid"]').on('change', function(){
   var label = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
   $('input[type=text]').val(label + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uEFx3/

Answer (score 3):

Just use value attributes to give the value you want.

```
<select name="scatid">
<optgroup label="June">
  <option value="June 2005">2005</option>
```

Comment: If you don't do it this way, the form results are indistinguishable when submitted to the server

Answer (score 2):

With the proviso that you don't actually want to do this:

```
$("#scatid").find("option:selected").parent().attr('label')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('select[name="scatid"]').change(function(){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').parent('optgroup').attr('label')+'  '+$(this).val());
});
});
```